# Makefile:182: recipe for target 'obj/convolutional_kernels.o' failed make: *** [obj/convolutional_kernels.o] Error 139

Tags: yolo, darknet, yolov4

While making darknet I got error
Segmentation fault (core dumped) Makefile:182: recipe for target 'obj/convolutional_kernels.o' failed make: *** [obj/convolutional_kernels.o] Error 139

Answer (score 0):

Open makefile and change the `NVCC = /usr/local/cuda-11/bin/nvcc` according to your version of cuda